# MS SQL how to have values from two row in one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to can I get values from two rows into one?
Like I have the following raw data

[image]

and I want to transform it to:
[image]

is this even possible with MS SQL?

these are excel sheets but I have the real data on the SQL Server

Explanation:
For each product_group_id I want to have the changes of discount_id and the discount_id should have the from_discount_id and to_discount_id ,

for each product_group_id there is a min row of two and for the last entry of product_group_id there should be no entry in the new table as now changes occur.

Comment: Use `MIN` and `MAX`?

Comment: I don't understand how you end up with data.  N rows per group seem to become N-1 rows in the output.

Comment: min and max would not help, because I could have i.e. 5 changes how should min max help? @Larnu

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as for the Nth one there is no changes anymore, it have no more entry after it

Comment: What if there is only one row in original set of data for that group of data ?

Comment: I have already excluded them, there is a min of two rows for each group @VBoka

Answer (score 0):

This is can be done using window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        h.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID,
        h.PID,
        LEAD(h.CHANGE_FROM) OVER (PARTITION BY h.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID 
                                   ORDER BY h.CHANGE_FROM ASC) AS CHANGE_FROM,
        h.PID as FROM_PID,
        h.DISCOUNT_ID as FROM_DISCOUNT_ID,
        LEAD(h.PID) OVER (PARTITION BY h.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID 
                          ORDER BY h.CHANGE_FROM ASC) as TO_PID,
        LEAD(h.DISCOUNT_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY h.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID
                                  ORDER BY h.CHANGE_FROM ASC) TO_DISCOUNT_ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID 
                           ORDER BY h.CHANGE_FROM DESC) RowNoDesc
    FROM
        ProductGroupDiscountHistory h
    ) WithNext
WHERE
    WithNext.RowNoDesc <> 1
ORDER BY
    WithNext.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID,
    WithNext.CHANGE_FROM
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try that and will tell if that worked for me :D

Comment: Apologies, I noticed I was pulling the "change from" from the wrong row. I've now updated so that it gets that right.

Comment: How did this work out for you? If it did the trick, do accept and upvote the answer. If not, let me know what the remaining issues are and I'll try to address them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how one can make it using lead func

```
with qq as (select id, 
                   change_from, 
                   discount_id from_discount_id, 
                   lead(discount_id) over(partition by id order by change_from) to_discount_id
           from test_t)

select * 
  from qq
 where to_discount_id is not null
 order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this without using `LEAD` or `LAG` if you wanted. The following statement uses an `INNER JOIN` condition which joins two rows if

- their `PRODUCT_GROUP_ID` is the same, *and*
- *either* the `CHANGE_TO` date of one row is 1 day before the `CHANGE_FROM` date of the next
- *or*  the `PID` of one row is 1 less than that of the next and the change dates are `min` respectively `max` for their `PID`.

which is the pattern I got from the data above.

Altogether

```sql
    SELECT   one.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID
           , one.PID
           , two.CHANGE_FROM
           , one.PID as FROM_PID
           , one.DISCOUNT_ID as FROM_DISCOUNT_ID
           , two.PID as TO_PID
           , two.DISCOUNT_ID as TO_DISCOUNT_ID
      FROM tab one
INNER JOIN tab two
        ON one.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID = two.product_GROUP_ID
           AND (DATEADD(DAY, 1, one.CHANGE_TO) = two.CHANGE_FROM
                OR one.PID = two.PID - 1
                   AND one.CHANGE_FROM IN (SELECT MAX(CHANGE_FROM) FROM tab WHERE PRODUCT_GROUP_ID = one.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID AND PID = one.PID)
                   AND two.CHANGE_FROM IN (SELECT MIN(CHANGE_FROM) FROM tab WHERE PRODUCT_GROUP_ID = one.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID AND PID = two.PID)
                )
      ORDER BY one.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID, one.PID, two.CHANGE_FROM
;
```

produces your desired result.

You can test it in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ddee4b8546de347b5478ca4ed734fdd1).